# Computing the centroid manually seems to affect the distance in GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, pandas

Consider this simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd

# read geodata for five nyc boroughs
gdf_nyc = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('nybb'))
# read geodata for international cities
gdf_cities = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_cities'))

# convert to a meter projection
gdf_nyc.to_crs(epsg=3857, inplace=True)
gdf_cities.to_crs(epsg=3857, inplace=True)
```

now we keep the `Point` for Washington D.C. and compute the centroid of each borough by hand.

```
mypoint = gdf_cities.loc[gdf_cities.name == 'Washington, D.C.']
gdf_nyc['mycentroid'] = gdf_nyc.geometry.centroid
```

And now I compute the distance between each borough and DC (using my manually created `centroid` and directly using `geometry.distance`). As you can see, the two results are close, but not equal. Why? I thought `.distance()` would use the `centroid` as well.

```
gdf_nyc.geometry.apply(lambda x: mypoint.distance(x))/1000000
Out[59]: 
        186
0  0.384423
1  0.416186
2  0.412520
3  0.419511
4  0.440293

gdf_nyc.mycentroid.apply(lambda x: mypoint.distance(x))/1000000
Out[60]: 
        186
0  0.400426
1  0.441408
2  0.424355
3  0.434527
4  0.450200
```

Comment: Wait...  You're calculating distance in Web Mercator? Time to start over again, with a projection in which distance has meaning.

Comment: @Vince sorry but I think epsg=3857 is in meters? what is wrong here?

Comment: I am getting a distance of about 384 km... about right

Comment: Web Mercator is a huge trap.  The units present as meters, but they aren't, since the poles are infinitely far from the Equator. This is a known flaw in web mapping and the reason Greenland shows as larger than South America, when it's really a seventh the size. Any distances generated in 3857 need to be scooped out of your data like a cat box needs cleaning, for the same reason.

Comment: thanks for the tip. Which other projection would you suggest?

Comment: I generally use spheroidal calculation directly from WGS84 degrees, but for places in the same UTM zone, UTM can be used. Or the UGGS CONUS Albers. or a custom Azimuthal Equidistant, centered on Washington, DC. Pretty much "anything but Web Mercator".

Comment: for instance EPSG:6350?

Comment: that still returns two slightly different distances. Am I missing something? Thanks @Vince for your help

Comment: Distance from a polygon is from the closest edge, not the centroid.

Comment: ah thank you so much!